# Удалить значение из таблицы

Tags: php, mysql

Есть колонка в таблице, в которую записываются id через запятую - "150,90,555,765,210".
И есть переменная, которая содержит id, которое нужно удалить из колонки - "$removeid = 555;".
Можно ли как-то через mysql-запрос удалить из колонки число, которое содержится в переменно, естественно, вместе с лишней запятой?
Есть пример, но он не удаляет запятую. Если добавить запятую в **'$removeid'** в начало или конец, то если удаляемое значение будет в самом начале, то значение не удалится

```
UPDATE table SET ids = REPLACE(ids, '$removeid', '')
```

Comment: Не должно быть, чтобы записывались id через запятую. Это отношение многое ко многому или одно к многому - значит у вас должна быть третья таблица.

Comment: Вернее, если одно к многому, то у обладателей этих id должно быть поле, указывающее, к какому id оно относится.

Comment: @Miron я ничего не понял

Comment: То есть вам нужно создать третью таблицу со следующим содержанием(допустим, что id строки, обладающей строкой "150,90,555,765,210", - 999): 999, 150; 999, 90; 999, 555; и тд.

Comment: @Miron У меня тогда очень много значений будет записываться. В таблице есть колонки **userid** где id пользователей и **ids** где перечисляются вот эти id (постов, например)

Comment: "тогда очень много значений будет записываться" - ТАК И ДОЛЖНО БЫТЬ. Именно так работает База данных.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Если уж так сильно хочется записать множественные связи в строку, то удалить конкретное число из любой позиции можно таким запросом:

```
$query = "UPDATE table "
       . "SET ids = TRIM(',' FROM REPLACE(CONCAT(',', ids, ','), '," . (int)$removeid . ",', ','))"
       . "WHERE ...";
```

Comment: Вот это работает. Спасибо большое

Answer (score -1):

Смотрите в сторону использования REGEX_REPLACE с RLIKE:

```
UPDATE `table_name` 
SET         
column_name = REGEXP_REPLACE(column_name,regex_pattern_to_find,replaceable_text)
WHERE
column_name RLIKE 'regex_pattern_to_find'
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50309333/mysql-regexp-replace-with-update)

Comment: В страшном сне такой лид не приснится. "джун: я хочу вот так накостылить. лид:Что ты делаешь! Вот так можно накостылить гораздо лучше!"

Comment: @Ипатьев каков вопрос, таков и ответ. Учить кого-то думать по-другому когда они об этом даже и не просят - занятие неблагодарное. Можно только надеятся что они сами додумаются и попытаются думать иначе, качественно перейдя на следующий уровень, нагородя костылей в процессе. Через тернии - к звёздам, так сказать.

Comment: Дада, и свистеть при этом "я такой весь из себя тимлид". Впрочем что это я. На большом сайте каждый второй вопрос про ошбку синтаксиса - либо от сеньора, либо от СТО. Почему индусам можно на нам нельзя

Comment: Вам бы, батенька, собственную GeekBrains открывать, да вразумлять пачками регистрирующихся в день у нас новичков уму-разуму, тов. @Ипатьев ;)